# What computers and keyboards are in the eleventh Doctor's console?

Tags: doctor-who

The eleventh Doctor's TARDIS has lots of retro equipment in its console. I see some computers or keyboards. Has anyone identified them? I would not be surprised if something very British were in there...

Comment: Do you have any stills? (And if you do, wouldn't *computer* experts be of more help to you than TV experts?) ;)

Comment: Hey hey now, there's plenty of us here that also post on some of the more technically inclined sites. ;) But yes, please post pictures of what you're asking about, specifically. Shots with the 11th doctor in them would be preferred as that's who you're asking about.

Comment: @MattD Will try to do this later, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Arne Which TARDIS do you mean? 11 had 2 different designs during the show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**One appears to be an old National Grid keyboard**

This promotional image:

[image: TARDIS keyboard]

appears to have been identified on the [TARDIS builders blog](http://tardisbuilders.com/index.php?topic=4581.0), although the keys are in a slightly different position, so may be a slight variation:

[image: National Grid Keyboard]

Additionally, the sub-section on [Console Reference](http://tardisbuilders.com/index.php?board=26.0) has a lot of background information and photos, so may hold more information.